# Adicionando caractere em uma string

Tags: string, python-2.7, imutabilidade

Boa pessoa minha dúvida e a seguinte, eu tenho a seguinte situação:

eu tenho a seguinte variável

```
>>> a = "EXAMPLE"
```

Vamos supor que tive que remover a letra "M" destra string, neste caso faria

```
>>> a = a.replace("M", "")
```

Então sabendo-se que as string são imutáveis, sé por acaso eu quise-se retornar com string "M" na mesma posição, para que a mesma retorna-se para seu formato original que seria EXAMPLE". Obrigado.

Comment: Relendo sua pergunta, não tenho certeza se entendi a dúvida. Você está querendo saber se "volta" pro mesmo objeto após a reinserção da letra "M", por ser imutável? Se for isso, veja minha resposta abaixo. Se era outra coisa que você queria perguntar, favor [edit] a pergunta esclarecendo isso. P.S. Se a dúvida não for específica do Python 2.7, sugiro retaguear a mesma só com `python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesmo se você reinserir a letra retirada, você ainda estaria criando uma nova string, pois como você mesmo apontou elas são imutáveis, então tanto retirar quanto colocar criam novos objetos. Isso pode ser verificado facilmente observando o [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) do objeto:

```
>>> a = "EXAMPLE"
>>> id(a)
32844376L
>>> b = a.replace("M", "")
>>> id(b)
32845176L
>>> c = b[:3] + "M" + b[3:]
>>> id(c)
32843016L
>>> c
'EXAMPLE'
```

Muito embora as strings sejam imutáveis, o Python não "cacheia" as mesmas por padrão. Se você quiser uma string única - que possa ser comparada só pelo endereço de memória (por eficiência) - você precisa explicitamente dizer pro Python colocá-la na cache, usando [`intern`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern):

```
>>> a = intern("EXAMPLE")
>>> id(a)
32843976L
>>> b = intern(a.replace("M", ""))
>>> id(b)
32844256L
>>> c = intern(b[:3] + "M" + b[3:])
>>> id(c)
32843976L
```

(entretanto, se nenhuma referência adicional existir pra string cacheada, ela pode ser recolhida pelo coletor de lixo e uma nova ser criada no futuro)

Comment: entendi, funcionou perfeitamente. Esse intern que vc informou seria  no caso de eu manipular dados na memória. Seria isso

Comment: Não, o `intern` simplesmente garante que duas strings iguais (no mesmo momento da execução) sejam representadas pelo mesmo objeto. Ou seja, se você coloca uma string retornada pelo `intern` em uma estrutura de dados, e depois tenta pesquisar nessa estrutura usando uma string também retornada pelo `intern`, então ele pode encontrar esse dado sem ter que comparar caractere por caractere, olhando só pelo endereço de memória. Entretanto, não sei quais estruturas de dados do Python se aproveitam desse fato, nem como isso funciona internamente.

Comment: Beleza, valeu ajudou bastante obrigado.